# String converted to integer during indexation

Tags: python, type-conversion

I'm creating a program to check if a user's inputted guess is correct(much like pigs and bulls).
The correct code is generated by the computer.

During the process of checking if the user inputted is correct a string variable is changed(or so I think) to an int and stops being iterable. I've tried doing some debugging with *print(type())* to check for the type of the variable.  Right up until the moment it's being iterated, the variable is a String, yet I get a *TypeError: argument of type 'int' is not iterable.*

**here's the code:**

```
def create_code(creator=list):
    creator = [random.randint(0, 9) for index in range(0, 4)]
    return creator

def guesses():
    state = True
    user_inputs = []
    while state:
        get_user_input = str(input('Please insert your 4 digit guess: '))
        user_inputs.append(get_user_input)
        for index in range(0,len(get_user_input)+1):
            touro(index, get_user_input[index]) #goes to touro to check if the number inputted is in the code and in the correct position

def touro(index, user_input):
    t = 0
    print(type(user_input[index]))#this returns str
    print(type(create_code))#this returns list
    if user_input[index] in create_code()[index]:
        print('th')
        t += 1
    else:
        pigs(index, user_input)#this function is just to check if the inputted number currently being iterated is even in the code
        print('ty')
    return t
```

**Error:**

```
    File "C:/Users/Miguel/PycharmProjects/untitled1/Trabalho1.py", line 14, in guesses
    touro(index, get_user_input[index])
  File "C:/Users/Miguel/PycharmProjects/untitled1/Trabalho1.py", line 27, in touro
    if user_input[index] in create_code()[index]:
TypeError: argument of type 'int' is not iterable
```

I don't get what i'm doing wrong, and I haven't any questions with similar problems, does anybody now what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Could you provide a minimal, *verifiable* example that shows your error?

Comment: Can you print this `create_code()[index]`?

Comment: I'm also guessing the create_code() is the problem. Also you should check what you want that touro function to do anyways, because it returns a value but you don't use it

Comment: I've added the code_generator function and the print(type(code_generator))

Comment: You wrote "print(type(create_code))#this returns list". Now Im confused. is create_code a function or a global variable? Also we dont just want to see the type, we want to see the actual data structure. So try and literally print(create_code() ) please

Comment: I'm assuming create_code() returns a list of integer instead of strings. If so, just parse it to string when constructing and the error should vanish

Comment: Change this `if user_input[index] in create_code()[index]:` to `if user_input[index] in create_code():` or `if user_input[index] == create_code()[index]:` whichever you feel would make sense

Comment: @GarbageCollector he wrote that create_code() returns a list tho, and the error states "int" specifically so that probably won't solve it. It's more likely create_code() is supposed to return a list of strings and he wants to check if his character is part of a specific one of them

Comment: @Banana `create_code` returns a list and `in` operator expects an iterable. Thats why he is getting this error. He either have to check equality or check existence inside list.

Comment: Not sure I get your point, lists are iterable, just not iterators. However: why do you hand over user_input[index], which should be a single character, and then access it at [index] again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The snippet `create_code()[index]` does the following:

- creates a list of integers, i.e. `[7, 4, 7, 0]`
- selects and returns the integer located at index i.e. at index equals `2`, which would return a `7`

The `in` statement cannot be used to search for a string character in an integer.